# What is the name of a set of unitary matrices obeying $\{U_i^\dagger, U_j\} = U_i^\dagger U_j + U_j U_i^\dagger = 2\delta_{ij}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If it weren't for the Hermitian conjugation this looks like a Clifford Algebra.

Comment: Looks strangely similar to a Clifford relation

Comment: @Chris Indeed, and I'm not even sure the $^\dagger$ actually makes so much of a difference...

Comment: @TobiaKeinzler maybe it’s similar to the product you get when you use a hermitian form instead of a complex bilinear one